# Why does my google calendar look ok on my computer but all the details change to code on my iphone?

Tags: google-calendar, text-formatting

I create events on my laptop but when I view them on iPhone all the text in the description section turns to code. I have figured out to not cut and paste, but even if I type in the details it changes ONLY on my phone.

Comment: In the Google Calendar app on your phone, or are you using a mobile web browser? If the former, you really want to ask this at [apple.se] instead.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the information given, I would try to re-sync everything from scratch. Re-install google calendar on your phone (it will be an icon on your home page).

If you need more instructions on how to do this, please let me know and I will assist!